# Is there a way to import freight?

Tags: simcity-2013

My question on Sim City (2013) is:

Is there any way to import freight for my commercial zones? There is a big industrial city connected to me by road and rail. But I can't seem to get enough freight for my shops and businesses. Is there a way to import this freigth from the international market?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a trade depot in the city? I think you need one to accept freight.

Answer (score 1):

Freight cannot be bought on the market.  Freight can be transmitted via region by a street connected neighbor overproducing.  The trucks from that city will automatically go directly to your Commercial buildings.  Freight Warehouse is counter-productive because freight does not move between warehouse and Commercial buildings.

However, you might be misled by the message.  Commercial buildings will abandon for lack of selling 100% of goods, and then will complain for lack of freight.  Freight is a bonus like tourist souvenirs, and freight arriving at commercial buildings is not essential for preventing abandonment.  Reduce/spread Commercial buildings until all goods are sold each 5 AM.

More information: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4Xmc.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a trade depot (though preferrably trade port, since it can hold more resources) and add freight lots there. I think it goes like this, overall: freight is made in factories (industrial zones), then goes on to shops (commercial zones) and then on to residents (residential zones) who buy the stuff from stores.